# How to convert Platform::Array<uint16> to raw int16*

Tags: windows-runtime, c++-cx

I have a Runtime Component where I need a raw pointer `int16*` from some given `Platform::Array<uint16>`. Like `int16 buffer[20]`, but I don't know the size during compile time.

How can I get this without giving the buffer a fixed size?

```
ConvertArray(const Platform::Array<uint16>^ bytes)
{
    int16 buffer[bytes->Length];   // doens't work
    int16 buffer[20]; // works, but I never know what size it needs to be
    ....
}
```

Any suggestions how to do this?

Comment: Use a `std::vector<int16>`. Or `Platform::Array<int16>`

Comment: I realy need the a `int16[]` because the third pary library I'm using (old c) only excepts `int16 const *data`

Comment: That doesn't mean you can't use a vector to *store* it. You can get the raw pointer from the vector with `.data()`. Maybe the same can be done with `Platform::Array` (which I don't know enough to tell), so you don't need to do any conversion at all.

Comment: Tnx for the Hint; ref new Platform::Array<int16> and then ->Data worked great! 
I Would like to mark your answer, but can't do on a comment.

Comment: I did write it as an answer now. But why do you use `new` another Platform Array? You already have one. Are you doing this, and copying the data, just because the one type is unsigned and the other isn't? That's unnecessary. You can cast the raw pointer from `.Data()` to a different one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If everything you need is to get a **raw pointer** to the data, for example to give it to some C library, you *usually* can obtain such a pointer from a higher level data-structure.

You can obtain the raw pointer from a `Platform::Array<T> array` with `array.Data()`.

Similarly, you can obtain the raw pointer from a `std::vector<T> vec` with `vec.data()`.

But one thing to note when you do this: Depending on the data structure (please refer to its documentation), the raw pointer obtained in this way might get **invalidated** when modifying the data structure. In the case of a `std::vector` this happens when inserting or deleting elements (i.e. changing the size), because the implementation might choose to reallocate a memory of different size for the content.

Comment: `Platform::Array<T> array` with `array.Data()` worked perfertly with me, to use for older third party code that not use `Platform::Array<T>`. But I could not find the `Data` in `std::vector<T> vec`, in my version... maybe because it's an Observable. 
Tnx for the answer.